# Power BI: Do not output empty leaves in the hierarchy, Power BI / VS Report Builder, Joining two or more tables

Tags: matrix, powerbi, hierarchy, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

Project [Project PowerBI](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B2g2YCTURVpU_lCSmaE3Ke6tSy60AiNy)

I ask for your help, have already climbed a bunch of resources and can not find a suitable solution

The problem is this:

There is a heterogeneous hierarchy in the visual element (matrix), how to remove the empty leaves (levels) of the hierarchy? (project in the attachment)
As far as I saw, there are still no standard methods, but still. From the side of logic, you just need not to calculate the measure for empty elements in the line (the hierarchy goes line by line for each unique value) or replace the value with 0 by it and filter the measure so that 0 is not displayed

- how to make hierarchy in columns with expand / collapse +/-, I saw and used different visual elements in the marketplace None came up, the most suitable was "Zebra BI", but it terribly slows down a million records in the fact table and adding several levels to the hierarchy columns, just at some point can’t load anything (or I'm doing something wrong, but it seems hard to make a mistake somewhere)
- There is a report builder — either Power BI Report Builder or Visual Studio, and there the Reporting Services Projects project (as I understand it can be said the same thing) - we create and then upload Power BI reports to the server. It seems like he can do anything (this also applies to the second question), if you know that this is so and there are some examples, then I will be glad to study them, I just did not have time to work with him

There are different tables (matrix) on the layout (one below the other) have the same columns, but they have different rows and hierarchies by rows, they also have different measures.
2.1. How to glue two or more tables one under the other so that they can be viewed at the same time - when expanding the columns, did the columns expand in the two tables? (I understand that it is possible to do a full disclosure of the hierarchy of columns and filters to do everything synchronously, but in order to do the expansion at the top (detail), and all the tables were magic at once)

2.2 So that when expanding the hierarchies in the rows of the table, a vertical slider does not appear for each table separately, i.e. The matrix table was rubber and there was no collision to the table below. In Microstrategy, it happened that I created a table, cut a layout (canvas), inserted another table below the cut, or whatever, it turned out as if it were one piece and the tables were rubber and did not overlap.

In general, it is necessary - different tables, one under the other with different measures and row hierarchies, but with the same hierarchies of columns to make work as a whole. Again Report Builder to help? In the attached project, let's imagine that these are different tables and we need them to work as one.

I am waiting for your help, my knowledge is not enough and Google does not help, I don’t know how to contact him =)

Thanks!